# Drools IDE with debugger

Tags: ide, drools, jbpm

I am new to creating Drools DRL files and I have been using business-central packaged in latest jbpm artifacts as standalone web interface. I find the IDE for writing drl non intuitive, and validation errors keep stacking up even when I change the code and fix it. Is there a better development tool where we can check syntax, correct compilation errors and also debug/troubleshoot the rule definitions

Comment: I write all my rules in my regular IDE (IntelliJ IDEA). The Ultimate edition at least has Drools support, not sure about Community.  But I also don't do anything with jbpm, just straight-up drools, so I don't know if this will suit your needs.

Comment: Our firm has intellij Idea 2020 community version. I could not find any plugin for this. Writing rules as text files and debugging with system.out.println is not efficient. I am exploring eclipse plugin right now. I was wondering if redhat has a good IDE integrated with kieserver for quicker dev cycles.

Comment: There's no plugin necessary, it's build into the IDEA IDE itself. But perhaps that's only the paid 'ultimate' version and not the free community edition. If you download a new copy of ultimate you get 30 days free trial if you want to see if that fits your needs. The Eclipse IDE plugin stopped working for me around drools 5.2 so I can't comment there. I've never debugged via printlns, personally, I've always written listeners and put breakpoints them them and logged useful things like duration and rule hits.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, there's no such a thing.

The closest thing you could use with latest Drools is the Eclipse Plugin, but you have to use the `7.46.0.Final` ([source](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.56.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#_installing_and_using))

With IDEA community you can debug Drools' execution but you cannot put breakpoint inside consequences, and you don't get syntax highlighting out of the box.

The IDEA Ultimate has a Drools plugin but it's not developed by the same team (it's made by JetBrains instead of Red Hat) and has plenty of bugs ([source](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/idea?q=%23drools%20)) I'm not even sure it's maintained anymore.

Kogito has some [VS Code tooling](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kie-group.vscode-extension-kogito-bundle) but still doesn't support DRL files.